# Finding the recency of a customer

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which contains customer ID and number of trips each month. I need to find recency for the same. i.e number of months passed before the last visit, e.g. if the customer visited in months 2, 3 and 7. Recency is

```
     M1 <- NA 
     M2 <- NA
     M3 <- 1
     M4 <- 1 
     M5 <- 2
     M6 <- 3
     M7 <- 4
     M8 <- 1
```

[image]

I want to find this for every customer (key is customer id), for 18 months.

I tried using loops but don't know how to go about it

```
check <- ifelse(DF$trip[i]>DF$trip)

something <- function(year, month){
  for(i in 1:18000){
    ifelse(DF$trip[i]>0,check,break)
  }
}

for(i in 1:18000){
  ifelse(DF$id[i+1]=DF$id[i], something, break)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide a small subset of your data as well as your desired output? That way it will be easier for people to know how to help.

Comment: Thanks. I uploaded an image of the same

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way to do this but here is one way. We create a `row_number()` column for every `id` and `year` and subtract the current row number with a row number which is less than the current one and the last non-zero value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         recency = purrr::map_int(row, 
                      ~. - row[max(which(row < . & Trip != 0))])) %>%
  select(-row)


#      id  year Month  Trip recency
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     0    NA
# 2     1     1     2     1    NA
# 3     1     1     3     2     1
# 4     1     1     4     0     1
# 5     1     1     5     0     2
# 6     1     1     6     0     3
# 7     1     1     7     1     4
# 8     1     1     8     0     1
# 9     1     1     9     0     2
#10     1     1    10     0     3
#11    10     1     1     1    NA
#12    10     1     2     2     1
#13    10     1     3     0     1
#14    10     1     4     0     2
```

This throws a warning which can be ignored since it is for first row in each group where we have no row number which is less than 1.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 
10), year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Month = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Trip = c(0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0)),class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA,-14L))
```